# Data from React Hook not updating UI from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling to see what is wrong with my code here, but essentially the function from the useSongInfo hook is working, however it isn't updating the player UI.

I've attached both components below. Whenever I click a new song, I can see the new data coming through in the console.log(songInfo?.name), however it is not showing he dynamic image or dynamic text component data inside the Box.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening? I've also tried using Context to store the songInfo globally, however still get the same issue.

```
const Player = () => {
    const songInfo = useSongInfo()
    console.log(songInfo?.name, "song info from player");

  return (
    <Box
      position={"fixed"}
      bottom={0}
      left={0}
      right={0}
      bg={"gray.100"}
      height={"80px"}
    >
      <Box position={"relative"} w={12} h={12}>
        {songInfo?.album.images[1]?.url ? (
          <Image src={songInfo?.album.images[1]?.url} layout={"fill"} />
        ) : (
          <Box />
        )}
        <Text>{songInfo?.name} TEST</Text>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};


function useSongInfo() {
  const currentTrackId = "123"
  const spotifyAccessToken = "dummy-access-token"

  const [songInfo, setSongInfo] = useState<SpotifySong>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSongInfo = async () => {
      if (currentTrackId && spotifyAccessToken) {
        const trackInfo = await fetch(
          `https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${currentTrackId}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${spotifyAccessToken}`,
            },
          }
        ).then((res) => res.json());
        setSongInfo(trackInfo);
      }
    };
    fetchSongInfo();
  }, [currentTrackId, spotifyAccessToken]);

  return songInfo;
}
```

To show that values change on click, here are values from both songInfo?.name and songInfo?.album.images[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdTf7.png)?.url
[image]

Comment: Maybe `songInfo?.album.images[1]?.url` doesn't exist

Comment: `<Text>{currentSongInfo?.name} TEST</Text>` shouldn't that be `<Text>{songInfo?.name} TEST</Text>`?

Comment: Did you try inspecting `songInfo`? the image url may not be there in the way you expect. Also, where `currentSongInfo` is coming from?

Comment: Sorry have updated to songInfo, but yes still not working. I can confirm from console logs that both have values.

Comment: I have added a screenshot as well.

Comment: I would expect the song title "BEST INTEREST" to appear next to the word "TEST" in the player.

Comment: Try making the useEffect in useSongInfo async and await for fetchSongInfo